# Xamarin Forms IOS Not showing Images in Release Build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin forms application that uses Images in the IOS build from the Assets Catalogue.  If I build a debug version and deploy it to iPhone then the images display successfully.  When I build release through App Centre, images do not display.
Is anyone seeing this issue?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Does this happen to all the images in your project or only one image?

Comment: splash screen and app icon are fine, this is an image I use at the top of page works in debug not in release.

Comment: Can you try another image to check if the problem is caused by that specific image?

Comment: Ok so I have fixed it... bit strange tried different image which works elsewhere... tried to re-create image set still no joy.  So I changed image set name away from icon to a different name and bingo fixed!